# Оконное приложение на С++

Tags: c++, winapi

Выбивает ошибку:

> Серьезность   Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
>
> Ошибка    C2440   =: невозможно преобразовать "const char [9]" в "LPCWSTR"    Lab1    c:\users\валера\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\lab1\lab1\hello.cpp   15

```
#include <windows.h>
LONG WINAPI WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hwnd; // дескриптор окна
    MSG msg; // структура сообщения
    WNDCLASS w; // структура класса окна
                // Регистрация класса окна
    memset(&w, 0, sizeof(WNDCLASS));
    w.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    w.lpfnWndProc = WndProc; // имя оконной функции
    w.hInstance = hInstance;
    w.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(WHITE_BRUSH);
    w.lpszClassName = "My Class";
    RegisterClass(&w);
    // Создание окна
    hwnd = CreateWindow(L"MyClass",L"MyOkno",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 500, 300, 500, 380, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow); // отображение
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);          // перерисовка
                                 // Цикл обработки сообщений
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: А если так `w.lpszClassName = L"My Class";`?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Вроде нашел ответ на свой вопрос
Код не той среды

Answer (score 2):

Оберните все строки, передаваемые в WinAPI-функции, в `TEXT(...)`. Пример:

```
w.lpszClassName = TEXT("My Class");

hwnd = CreateWindow(TEXT("MyClass"), TEXT("MyOkno"), /* ... */
```

Тогда вам не придётся разбираться ни с опцией проекта *Configuration Properities -> General -> Charater Set*, ни с `A`/`W` вариантами функций, ни с префиксом `L` для строк.

К слову, в вашем случае настройка *Charater Set* была выставлена в `Use Multi-Byte Character Set` (поэтому варианты функций и структур по умолчанию и ожидали *LPCWSTR*), но в поле `w.lpszClassName` вы пытались записать (сильно упрощая) ASCII-строку (забыли добавить префикс `L` к `"My Class"`).

Answer (score 0):

Это распространённая ошибка с WINAPI.

`LPCWSTR - LONG POINTER CONST (наверное) WSTRING(WCHAR*)`

Варианты решения:

1. Использовать `wstring s = L"uu";`. Но тогда в `cout` уже `s` не передать(можно но оч сложно).
2. добавить буковку `A`:

   ```
   WNDCLASSA w;
   RegisterClassA(&w);
   ```

и можно использовать обычный `string`

3. Разобраться с юникодом указателями и классами `wstring` и `string`. Написать функции оператора `<<`  для `wstring` и т. д.

2 если хочется сразу. 1 если хочется сразу и весь функционал с юникодом. 3 для серьёзных проектов.

Comment: Текст вам отформатировал, но вопрос был вовсе не про `std::string` и `std::cout`.

Comment: Когда я начинал с WINAPI разбираться то мне эти сведения очень помогли бы. А с форматированием что-то у меня слетело вроде бы и 4 пробела а как код не подсвечивает.... А вопрос про подсказать был.

Comment: Эти четыре пробела были восприняты как отступ внутри списка. Для форматирования кода надо ещё четыре добавить.

Comment: `Но тогда в cout уже s не передать` — для этого есть `wcout`.

Comment: wcout хмм впервые слышу. Но в cout нельзя точно.

Comment: http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout — в этой статье `cout` и `wcout` рассматриваются в паре.

Comment: `LONG POINTER CONST WSTRING(WCHAR*)` - это что за бредятина?? Да и остальной ответ не сильно лучше.